# How can display attributr of type collection In angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object collection "ELEMENT_DATA". In the object I have an attribute "Activite" of type collection. I want to display this attribute in a .

here is my app.component.ts:

export class AppComponent {

```
ELEMENT_DATA: Patient[] = [
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Badre Labiad',
        Ne_le: new Date(1991, 9, 18),
        Activite: [{"name": 'PPC'}],
        Obs: '6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(1991, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: false
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Othman',
        Ne_le: new Date(1985, 5, 20),
        Activite: [{"name": 'O2'}],
        Obs: '6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: true
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Youness',
        Ne_le: new Date(1984, 9, 18),
        Activite: [{"name": 'Aidt'}],
        Obs: '6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: true
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Anouar',
        Ne_le: new Date(1996, 7, 10),
        Activite: [{"name": 'Vent'}, {"name": 'O2'}, {"name": 'PPC'}, {"name": 'Aéro'}, {"name": 'Aidt'}],
        Obs: '6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: false
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Oussama',
        Ne_le: new Date(1989, 9, 8),
        Activite: [{"name": 'PPC'}, {"name": 'Aéro'}, {"name": 'Aidt'}],
        Obs: '6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: true
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Badr',
        Ne_le: new Date(1989, 9, 18),
        Activite: [
            {
                "name": 'Vent'
            },
            {
                "name": 'O2'
            },
            {
            "name": 'PPC'
            }
            ],
        Obs: 'Obs: 6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: false
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Abdilah',
        Ne_le: new Date(1991, 8, 28),
        Activite: [{"name": 'Vent'}, {"name": 'Aidt'}],
        Obs: 'Obs: 6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: true
    },
];
```

}
here is my app.component.html :

```
<table id="fileActive" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

<ng-container matColumnDef="Nom_Prenom">
    <th class="nom sortable" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <div>Nom Prénom</div>
    </th>
    <td class="nom" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Nom_Prenom}} </td>
</ng-container>


<ng-container matColumnDef="Ne_le">
    <th class="naissance sortable date" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <div> Né(e)le</div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Ne_le | date }} </td>
</ng-container>


<ng-container matColumnDef="Activite">
    <th class="act" *matHeaderCellDef>
        <div>Activités prescites</div>
    </th>
    <tr *ngFor="let a of ELEMENT_DATA">
    <td mat-cell *ngFor="let b of a.Activite">
            <span >
                {{b.name}}
            </span>
    </td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
 .
 .
 .
```

I have tried all the solutions you can imagine but unfortunately without results.
If anyone has a solution for this I will be grateful. Thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly would you want to display the list? Maybe just join the activities' names with a.Activite.map(v=>v.name).join(', '); ?

Comment: @FrancescoManicardi thank you for you'r answer . 
I want to display the activities of my list in an html table

Comment: I understand, but how exactly? do you want a row for each activity? one table cell for each activity? or just all of the activities in one single table cell?

Comment: all activities in one cell

Comment: OK, how should the activitie names be separated from one another? with a comma?

Comment: he should be in <div>

Answer (score 0):

Move the *ngFor from the `<td>` to an html element inside of the td.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Activite">
    <th class="act" *matHeaderCellDef>
        <div>Activités prescites</div>
    </th>
    <tr *ngFor="let a of ELEMENT_DATA">
    <td mat-cell >
            <div *ngFor="let b of a.Activite">
                {{b.name}}
            </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I have activite but i have juste one activite (PPC) i think he desplay a first activite in collection

Comment: You only want to show the first activity's name?

Comment: no for example anouar have 5 activtes so i should show  [ vent  O2  PPC  Aéro  aidt ]

Comment: you'r solution give me this error " Cannot read property 'template' of undefined
    at MatRowDef.BaseRowDef.extractCellTemplate" . I add  *matCellDef="let element" in <td matcell> to resolve a problem. But i still have one activite

Answer (score 0):

to resolve my problem . I change the type of activite :

```
Activite: Array<string>
```

so i do this in :

app.component.ts :

```
export class AppComponent {




ELEMENT_DATA: Patient[] = [
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Badre Labiad',
        Ne_le: new Date(1991, 9, 18),
        Activite: ['O2'],
        Obs: '6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(1991, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: false
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Othman',
        Ne_le: new Date(1985, 5, 20),
        Activite: ['O2'],
        Obs: '6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: true
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Youness',
        Ne_le: new Date(1984, 9, 18),
        Activite: ['Aidt'],
        Obs: '6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: true
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Anouar',
        Ne_le: new Date(1996, 7, 10),
        Activite: ['Vent' , 'O2',  'PPC', 'Aéro', 'Aidt'],
        Obs: '6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: false
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Oussama',
        Ne_le: new Date(1989, 9, 8),
        Activite: ['PPC', 'Aéro', 'Aidt'],
        Obs: '6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: true
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Badr',
        Ne_le: new Date(1989, 9, 18),
        Activite: [ 'Vent','O2','PPC' ],
        Obs: 'Obs: 6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: false
    },
    {
        Nom_Prenom: 'Abdilah',
        Ne_le: new Date(1991, 8, 28),
        Activite: [ 'Vent', 'Aidt','NUT'],
        Obs: 'Obs: 6h48/ 30j',
        IAH: 'IAH 6',
        Fuites: 'Fuites : 12',
        Renouvellement: new Date(2021, 9, 18),
        Valider_AR: true
    },
];
```

}

and in my html ,i do this :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Activite">
    <th class="act" *matHeaderCellDef>
        <div>Activités prescites</div>
    </th>

    <td class="a" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <div *ngFor="let a of element.Activite">
            {{a}}
        </div>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```